# Filter recurring occurrences of event in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I have a couple if event-ids that I want to count. Some of these events occur multiple times per day, which I filter out with a DISTINCT(). Some of the events also occur on several days, however. As I count events per day, DISTINCT() does not get rid of the same event-id when it occurs across more than one day. I would like to check all data within a 28-day lookback window and only count an event-id on days when it occurs the first time during this time lookback-window.

Currently, I try this

```
--Define calculation date range-- 
WITH DATE_RANGE AS (
    SELECT
        '2023-07-12'::DATE AS START_DATE,
        '2023-07-18'::DATE AS END_DATE
),

DAYS AS (
    SELECT
        -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 0) AS I,
        START_DATE + i AS DAY_DT,
        START_DATE + I - 28 AS CUTOFF_DT
    FROM DATE_RANGE
        JOIN TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 10000 )) AS X
        QUALIFY I < 1 + END_DATE - START_DATE
),

--Define the range of the lookback-window
TRANS_RANGE AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(CUTOFF_DT) AS TRANS_START_DATE,
        MAX(DAY_DT) AS TRANS_END_DATE
    FROM DAYS
),

--Draw all transactions that happened during the specified TRANS_RANGE--
TRANS_RAW_EVENTS AS (
    SELECT
        DAY_DT,
        EVENT_ID
    FROM
        EVENTS AS E,
        TRANS_RANGE AS D
    WHERE
        E.DAY_DT BETWEEN D.TRANS_START_DATE AND D.TRANS_END_DATE
),

--Find first occurrence of all events--
TRANS_RAW_EVENTS_WITH_WINDOW AS (
    SELECT
        DAY_DT,
        EVENT_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANSACTION_ID ORDER BY DAY_DT) AS RN
    FROM TRANS_RAW_EVENTS
),

--Get calculation data--
PROCESSING_EVENTS AS (
    SELECT
        E.DAY_DT,
        E.EVENT_ID
    FROM EVENTS AS E,
    DATE_RANGE AS D
    WHERE
        E.DAY_DT BETWEEN D.START_DATE AND D.END_DATE
),

SELECT
    A.DAY_DT AS DAY_DT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IFF(C.RN = 1, A.EVENT_ID, NULL)) AS EVENTS
FROM PROCESSING_EVENTS AS A
    JOIN DAYS AS B
    ON A.DAY_DT = B.DAY_DT
        LEFT JOIN TRANS_RAW_EVENTS_WITH_WINDOW AS C
        ON
        A.EVENT_ID = C.EVENT_ID AND
        A.DAY_DT >= C.DAY_DT - 28 AND
        A.DAY_DT <= C.DAY_DT
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

This does nearly what I want, but it kicks out all repeated occurrences of an event-id within the entire time frame defined in TRANS_RANGE. For instance, if an event-id occurs on 14 June it would  not be counted ever, as its global first occurrence was on 14 June and RN would not be 1 for any other date in DAYS. However, it should not be counted when it then occurs next on 12 July (as 14 June is within the 28-day lookback window) but it should be counted if it only occurs next on 14 July (as the 28-day lookback window for this date ends on 16 June). How can I make this re-occurrence filtering dynamic in that way?

Comment: If you could provide a sample data set for TRANS_RAW_EVENTS and the expected output, it would help in formulating a response. My first thought is that rather than using DISTINCT, you should consider using QUALIFY to isolate the first daily occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mostly seems like a rolling window filter problem, so lets build a rolling filter:

```
create or replace function rolling_window(DAY FLOAT)
  RETURNS TABLE (DAY FLOAT)
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
as '{
initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
     this.day = 0.0;
    },
processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
    if(row.DAY > this.day){
      this.day = row.DAY + 28.0;
      rowWriter.writeRow({DAY: row.DAY});
    }  
   }
}';
```

now we can feed the data in:

```
WITH fake_date(day_dt, event_id, extra) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-06-01'::date, 1, 10),
    ('2023-06-02'::date, 1, 11),
    ('2023-06-10'::date, 1, 12),
    ('2023-07-01'::date, 1, 13),
    ('2023-07-14'::date, 1, 14),
    ('2023-07-15'::date, 2, 15)
)
select *,
    datediff('day', '2020-01-01'::date, fd.day_dt)::float as day_dt_float
from fake_date as fd
,table(rolling_window(datediff('day', '2020-01-01'::date, fd.day_dt)::float) over (partition by fd.event_id order by fd.day_dt, fd.extra)) as rw
;
```

| DAY_DT | EVENT_ID | EXTRA | DAY | DAY_DT_FLOAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | 10 | 1,247 | 1,247 |
| 2023-07-01 | 1 | 13 | 1,277 | 1,277 |
| 2023-07-15 | 2 | 15 | 1,291 | 1,291 |

Now you have the first row per 28 day rolling window. I added the extra column to force the date data to have a stable sort order. But if you have datetime, with no millisecond duplicates this will not be needed.

now if you are want all original rows also, you can change the output to always output, and return a bool true/false, and use that in other processing.

```
create or replace function rolling_window(DAY FLOAT)
  RETURNS TABLE (FIRST_28_WINDOW boolean)
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
as '{
initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
     this.day = 0.0;
    },
processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
    if(row.DAY > this.day){
      this.day = row.DAY + 28.0;
      rowWriter.writeRow({FIRST_28_WINDOW: true});
    } else{
      rowWriter.writeRow({FIRST_28_WINDOW: false});
    }
   }
}';

WITH fake_date(day_dt, event_id, extra) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-06-01'::date, 1, 10),
    ('2023-06-02'::date, 1, 11),
    ('2023-06-10'::date, 1, 12),
    ('2023-07-01'::date, 1, 13),
    ('2023-07-14'::date, 1, 14),
    ('2023-07-15'::date, 2, 15)
)
select *
from fake_date as fd
,table(rolling_window(datediff('day', '2020-01-01'::date, fd.day_dt)::float) over (partition by fd.event_id order by fd.day_dt, fd.extra)) as rw
;
```

| DAY_DT | EVENT_ID | EXTRA | FIRST_28_WINDOW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | 10 | TRUE |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | 11 | FALSE |
| 2023-06-10 | 1 | 12 | FALSE |
| 2023-07-01 | 1 | 13 | TRUE |
| 2023-07-14 | 1 | 14 | FALSE |
| 2023-07-15 | 2 | 15 | TRUE |